# Call Function of inside function in Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I have some Python code in below written in Python 2.7 and I have problem with calling a function form inside another function.

```
class CSP:

def __init__(self, matrix):
    self.X = []
    self.D = []
    self.C = []
    self.matrix = util.copyMatrix(matrix)
    self.counter = 0
    # Matrix to Vector
    vector = [item for line in self.matrix for item in line]
    chars = map(str, vector)
    result = ['*' if item == '0' else item for item in chars]

def solve(self):
    """ Returns the result matrix.
    The sudoku matrix is self.matrix.
    Use util.printMatrix in purpose of debugging if needed. """

    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    def init(self,result):
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(1,10):
                var = var_char[i]+str(j)
                self.X.append(var)
                domain = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
                self.D.append(domain)
        gamelist = result
        for i in range(len(gamelist)):
            if(re.match("\d+",gamelist[i])):
                self.D[i] = set([int(gamelist[i])])
        self.set_constraints()

      #########################################################################
    def set_constraints(self):
        for x in self.X:
            for y in self.X:
                if((x[0] == y[0] and x[1] != y[1]) or (x[1] == y[1] and x[0] != y[0])):
                    flag = True
                    for c in self.C:
                        if(x in c and y in c):
                            flag = False
                    if(flag):
                        self.C.append(set([x,y]))

        for a in [0,3,6]:
            for b in [0,3,6]:
                self.set_cube_constraints(a,b)
```

How to call `init()` function in `solve()` and also call `self.set_constraint()` inside `init()` function?

Comment: It's a bad idea to call `__init__` inside other method. I don't think you're able to call `self.set_constraint()` inside `__init__`, if you have a need for this, you should define `set_constraint` as a regular method.

Comment: @laike9m: the method the OP is talking about is `init()`, not `__init__()`

Comment: @SsRr: please fix your indentation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I see. Then there's not much to say.

Comment: You can't define class methods inside another one. To call `init()` from `solve()` — which is one — you'll need to use `init(self, result)` rather than `self.init(result)` as you normally would if it was a method. Likewise, you'll need to use `set_constraints(self)` instead of `self.set_constraints()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within function `solve()`, `init()` is a function, not a method. Therefore it can only be called in the same manner that any other unbound function can be called: by passing the correct number of arguments to it. This would work:

```
init(self, results)
```

Note that you need to explicitly pass a reference to the object in `self` because `init()` is not a method. Within `solve()` `self` refers to the `CSP` instance, so this should work.

However, `set_constraints()` is also a normal function, so you can not call it from `init()` with `self.set_constraints()`, but `set_constraints(self)` should work. Note that you need to declare function `set_constraints()` *before* `init()` otherwise you will get a "referenced before assignment" error.

Having said all that, this is just awful. Why not make `init()` and `set_constraints()` proper methods of the class?

Answer (score 0):

set_constraints is not a part of the class and therefore cannot be called with self.
If you put it one level up (remove one indentation level of it) then your code should work better.

I can see that this is some kind of coding exercise and you are told to write code in one particular place. I think you may be overcomplicating the answer because what you are coding here looks very messy by design and you should probably split out your functionality a lot more if this should be considerered clean code.